# How to get rid of from overbooking car rental website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a car rent site where people can book a car for their needs,but problem is my vehicles are limited so after booking a car i want to show an alert for the next 1 hour as it is overbooked immediately to my customers as no one can book it again within next 1 hour.
Here is my approach-

- fetching only today's booking info
- checking every vehicle is it    booked or not
- if it is booked then count the booking time and current time and
  compare them is it equal to or less then 1 hour.
- if it returns true then show the alert

now problem is how can I remove this MSG after 1 hour?

any code example would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_transient` function after someone booked a car. I assume a car is post type and all post have a unique ID. So after a car is booked you create a transient which expires after one hour. [Check Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/). Your code might have the next logic.

```
set_transient( $post_id . '_car_is_booked', true, HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
```

You set transient for `HOUR_IN_SECONDS` it is a special WordPress variable and after one hour it will be removed from the database automatically. So to find our is this car is booked or not you can use function `get_transient` [get_transient Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient).

```
// return false if option does not exists 
get_transient( $post_id . '_car_is_booked' );
```

And if `transient` for specific post ID exists it means the car is booked less then one hour ago.